# How to fetch remaining energy of all neighbor nodes in Unetstack?

Tags: unetstack

I have developed an energy model that can be loaded for every node present in the network. This model calculates transmitting and receiving energy.
Now what I want to do is if a node request all it's neighboring nodes then those neighbor nodes should reply back by sending their remaining energy values so that the node can decide which neighbor has higher energy level.

How to implement this and how that requesting node will fetch all energy values received
from various neighbor nodes?

This is my energy model :

```
import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.*
import org.arl.unet.phy.*
import java.math.*
import Java.util.*

class EnergyModel extends UnetAgent {

int neighbor, addr
float neighbor_distance;
def ranging
def  init_energy = 10
def dist
def data
def depth
def C = 1.3312e-9       // empirical constant
static def Tot_bits
def fr = 10           //carrier freq.(Khz)
def d = 0.036*Math.pow(fr,1.5)    //Thorp's constant
static def source

static HashMap<Integer, Integer[]> map = new HashMap<>(); 

def sum=0.0,avg=0.0,count=0;

 public void startup() {
  AgentID phy = agentForService(Services.PHYSICAL);
  subscribe (topic(phy));

  ranging = agentForService Services.RANGING;
  subscribe topic(ranging);

  def nodeInfo = agentForService Services.NODE_INFO;
  addr = nodeInfo.address;

  depth = nodeInfo.location[2] 
  map.put(addr, nodeInfo.location); 

  }

 public void processMessage(Message msg) {

   if (msg instanceof DatagramFailureNtf){

   System.out.println "\n\tDatagramFailureNtf occured!!\nt"+msg.toString()
    println "\n\t BadFrameNtf occured !!!!\n\t"+msg.toString()

  }

   if (msg instanceof DatagramNtf && msg.protocol == Protocol.DATA) {              
       count++  

       neighbor = msg.from;
       source = msg.from;
       data = msg.getData()
       int[] loc1 = map.get(source)
       int[] loc2 = map.get(msg.getTo())
       def x = loc1[0] - loc2[0]
       def y = loc1[1] - loc2[1]
       def distance = Math.sqrt((x)*(x) +(y)*(y));
       def bits=32
       Tot_bits = bits*data.size()

       System.out.println "\n\tNumber of bits sent :"+Tot_bits

       dist = distance/1000.0      // converting the distance in Km.

       BigDecimal Tx_EG = new BigDecimal("1"); // Or BigInteger.ONE 

    Tx_EG = Tx_EG.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(Tot_bits*50e-9+ Tot_bits*                 
        (0.001)*dist*(depth*-0.001)*C*Math.pow(Math.E,d*dist))); 
       init_energy = init_energy - Tx_EG ;
       sum = sum + Tx_EG 
       avg = sum/count

       String value = String.valueOf(Tx_EG.doubleValue());
       System.out.println '\n\tTransmission Energy : '+value+" Joules";
       System.out.println '\tRemaining Energy : '+(init_energy)

       File file = new File("I:\\out.txt")
       def text = file.getText()

       System.out.println "ENERGY: -t "+text+" -i "+source+" -d      
        "+Tot_bits+" -e "+init_energy+"   T"
       println "ENERGY: -t "+text+" -i "+source+" -d "+Tot_bits+" -e  
          "+init_energy+"   T"
                 }

       if (msg instanceof RxFrameNtf && msg.protocol == Protocol.DATA){

       data = msg.getData()       // getting data
       System.out.println "\tData is :"+data
       def bits=32
       Tot_bits = bits*data.size()      //caculating total number of bits
       System.out.println "\tNumber of bits received :"+Tot_bits

       BigDecimal Rx_EG = new BigDecimal("1"); // Or BigInteger.ONE 

       Rx_EG = Rx_EG.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(Tot_bits*50e-9));        
       init_energy = init_energy - Rx_EG ;                                
       String value = String.valueOf(Rx_EG.doubleValue());
       System.out.println '\n\tReception Energy : '+value+" Joules";
       System.out.println '\tRemaining Energy : '+(init_energy)
       System.out.println '\tTime : '+msg.getRxTime()
       System.out.println '\tNode ID : '+msg.getTo()
       System.out.println "ENERGY: -t "+msg.getRxTime()+" -i 
        "+msg.getTo()+" -d "+Tot_bits+" -e "+init_energy+"   R"
       println "ENERGY: -t "+msg.getRxTime()+" -i "+msg.getTo()+" -d 
        "+Tot_bits+" -e "+init_energy+"   R"

     }

  if (msg instanceof BadFrameNtf){

      System.out.println "\n\tBadFrameNtf occured !!!!\n\t"+msg.toString()
      println "\n\t BadFrameNtf occured !!!!\n\t"+msg.toString()

     }

   if (msg instanceof CollisionNtf){

      System.out.println "\n\tCollision occured !!!!\n\t"+msg.toString()
      println "\n\tCollision occured !!!!\n\t"+msg.toString()

       }

         }

           void setup() {

              }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define application-specific PDUs to request this information and provide this information, and implement your own protocol to respond with appropriate response PDUs when a request PDU is received. See how to write your own application-specific protocols from the ping example (`samples/ping` folder in the simulator) in the developer's guide.

An alternative would be to expose the energy as an agent parameter for PHY, and request it using the [remote access](https://unetstack.net/default-stack.html#remote-access) service to use the `RemoteParamReq` to ask for it.

Comment: ok sir! got it. But is it possible to receive multiple PDUs, if yes then how to implement this?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by receive multiple PDUs. You can receive any number of PDUs and each can contain whatever information you want. To differentiate between them, you'd probably want a fixed header with a PDU type in it.

Comment: I want to receive multiple PDUs at a time at a particular node. so, is it possible?

Comment: Given that a modem receives only one frame at a time in the water, the PDUs are naturally serialized. But yet, you can receive any number of PDUs on a particular node. I don't quite understand what your concern is.